# RepoDb's BulkInsert Times Out Always

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, repodb

I'm currently on a challenge of inserting a large number of records into a sql server db for processing (over 7k records). I decided to try out Bulk Insert from RepoDB. But on testing the code, it always times out with this message:

> Message:    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Execution Timeout
> Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.   Data:
> HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server
> HelpLink.ProdVer: 16.00.1105
> HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
> HelpLink.EvtID: -2
> HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
> HelpLink.LinkId: 20476
> ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The wait operation timed out.
>
> Stack Trace:    SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean
> breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
> Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean
> callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
> TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean
> canAccumulate)   TdsParserStateObject.WriteBytes(ReadOnlySpan`1 b, Int32 len, Int32 offsetBuffer, Boolean canAccumulate, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Byte[] array)
> TdsParserStateObject.WriteByteArray(Byte[] b, Int32 len, Int32
> offsetBuffer, Boolean canAccumulate, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion)   TdsParser.WriteString(String s, Int32 length, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean canAccumulate)   TdsParser.WriteUnterminatedValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32 paramSize, Boolean isDataFeed)   <15 more frames...>   SqlConnectionExtension.BulkInsert(SqlConnection connection, String tableName, DataTable dataTable, Nullable`1
> rowState, IEnumerable`1 mappings, Nullable`1 options, String hints,
> Nullable`1 bulkCopyTimeout, Nullable`1 batchSize, Nullable`1 isReturnIdentity, Nullable`1 usePhysicalPseudoTempTable,
> SqlTransaction transaction)
> CommandsScheduler.EnqueueBulkAsync[T](IEnumerable`1 internalCommands) line 48   InternalCommandTests.EnqueueBulkCommands_Test() line 40   GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()   AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
> TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
> TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
> <>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0()
> DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext
> context, Action action)   --Win32Exception

But when I try BulkMerge, it works. Now this may serve what I need but I'm eager to know why Insert doesn't work and possibly compare both of them and choose which one is more efficient for me. According to my integration tests, BulkMerge completes insertion of 10k records in 5.7s. I wish to see how BulkInsert performs. Below is my code:

```
public Task EnqueueBulkAsync<T>(IEnumerable<ICommand<T>> internalCommands)
{
    using SqlConnection connection = new(_dbConnection.ConnectionString);

    var table = ConvertToDataTable(internalCommands);
    int rows = connection.BulkInsert("[DirectDebitInternalCommands]", table, batchSize: 200);

    _logger.LogInformation("Enqueued {Rows} commands", rows);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<ICommand<T>> internalCommands)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Guid));
    dt.Columns.Add("EnqueuedDate", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("ExecutionDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));

    foreach (var command in internalCommands)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = command.Id;
        dr["EnqueuedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
        dr["ExecutionDateTime"] = command.ExecutionDateTime.HasValue ? command.ExecutionDateTime.Value : DBNull.Value;
        dr["Type"] = _internalCommandsMapper.GetName(command.GetType());
        dr["Data"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(command, command.GetType());
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```